# Colocar dados de uma planilha em Excel no banco de dados

Tags: python, django, pandas

O banco de dados aqui da empresa gera um relatório em Excel, preciso guardar esses dados em um baco de dados, inicialmente o sqlite3, para poder exibir esses dados em um template Django futuramente.

Exemplo do exel:

```
Nome do profissional,"Situação atual","Endereco E_Mail","Site","Site 2","Nascimento",
ABDIAS VENCESLAU DA SILVA NETO,"Ativo","xxxxx@hotmail.com","","","07/07/1977",
```

Cada dado desses ficaria guardado no respectivo model do Django e no banco de dados.

Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso? Mandem sugestões por favor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta assim

*models.py*

```
class Funcionario(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255),
    situacao = models.BooleanField,
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    site = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    site2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    nascimento = models.DateField()
```

*services.py (ou qualquer outro arquivo)*

```
class ImportToDatabase(object):

    @staticmethod
    def import_data():
        with open('relatorio.csv') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for row in reader:
                obj, created = Funcionario.objects.get_or_create(
                    nome=row[0],
                    situacao=row[1],
                    email=row[2],
                    site=row[3],
                    site2=row[4],
                    nascimento=row[5]
                )
```

*views.py*

```
ImportToDatabase.import_data()
```

Se quiser usar o objeto Funcionario ele está carregado na variavel obj
Para saber se o registro foi inserido ou carregado, utilize a variável booleana "created".

Comment: Da pra explicar a logica mais ou menos ?

Comment: Criei um model Funcionario para armazenar as informações que receberei do arquivo .csv. No exemplo eu herdei de model mas se esse objeto não for representado no banco de dados, você pode herdar de object mesmo.
Criei a classe ImportToDatabase para lidar com a importação dos dados. O with funciona como um try finally, a função open vem do pacote csv e recebe como parâmetro o nome do arquivo que está na raiz do meu projeto. O reader armazena o conteúdo do arquivo, faço um for para percorrer as linhas. Obj, created é o retorno de get_or_create, e os argumentos passados é um map dos valores.